# How to find how many cores a process is using?

Tags: process-management

I have a eight core machine. How can I find out how many cores are used by processes that I see in `htop`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In htop, press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>to enter setup, then use the arrows to navigate the `Columns->Available Columns` menu, select `PROCESSOR` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>to add a processor column. Then <kbd>q</kbd> to get back to the main screen.

Comment: This is great, but I believe this only shows WHICH core is being used, it is important to note that each item is still only running on 1 core at a time. The author asked how many cores were in use, not which one.

Comment: For which cores are in use, you can use taskset -pc [pid]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ps -o pid,psr,comm -p <pid>`[1], it displays on which core the process runs right now. Do this multiple times, and you get all cores.

For example:

```
while true; do echo -ne "`ps -o pid,psr,comm -p <pid>`"; done
```

[1] http://ask.xmodulo.com/cpu-core-process-is-running.html

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the processes you will see in `htop` or `ps` are going to be individual threads or process that each run on one core, but you might notice many apps have several processes going to take advantage of the extra cores.